# How to test @NotBlank spring validation with JUnit? [RESOLVED]

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, validation, testing

I am trying to test validation I have a controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/product")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@CrossOrigin
public class ProductController {

private final ProductService productService;

@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
@PostMapping
public ProductResponse createProduct(@RequestBody @Valid ProductRequest request) {
    return productService.createProduct(request);
 }
}
```

service

```
@Slf4j
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ProductServiceImpl implements ProductService {

private final ProductMapper productMapper;
private final ProductRepository productRepository;

@Override
@Transactional
public ProductResponse createProduct(ProductRequest productRequest) {
    Product product = productMapper.mapToEntity(productRequest);
    Product savedProduct = productRepository.save(product);
    log.info("New product saved. Id = {}", savedProduct.getId());
    return productMapper.mapToResponse(savedProduct);
}

}
```

DTO with spring validation annotations for controller and service

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class ProductRequest {

    @NotBlank(message = "{name.not-blank}")
    private String name;

    @Positive(message = "{amount.positive}")
    private Integer amount;

    @Positive(message = "{price.positive}")
    private Double price;
}
```

Mesagge in message.properties file:

```
name.not-blank=Name field is required
```

the exceptions are handled in RestExceptionHandler:

```
@ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
protected ResponseEntity<ExceptionResponse> handleMethodArgumentNotValidException(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {
    String message = ex.getAllErrors().stream()
            .map(DefaultMessageSourceResolvable::getDefaultMessage)
            .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
    ExceptionResponse response = new ExceptionResponse(message);
    log.error(message);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

And if I launch the app, and don't fill the name field of ProductRequest, I get the message according to my messages.properties file: "Name field is required"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzLuU.png)

But, if I create test and don't fill the same field in creating ProductRequest:

```
public class ProductServiceTest {

private final ProductRepository productRepository = mock(ProductRepository.class);
private final ProductMapper productMapper = new ProductMapperImpl();
private final ProductServiceImpl productService =
        new ProductServiceImpl(
                productMapper,
                productRepository);

@Test
void whenEmptyNameProduct() {
    var productRequest = buildProduct();
    var product = productMapper.mapToEntity(productRequest);
    when(productRepository.save(any())).thenReturn(product);
    var productResponse = productMapper.mapToResponse(product);
    MethodArgumentNotValidException thrown = assertThrows(
            MethodArgumentNotValidException.class,
            () -> productService.createProduct(productRequest));
    assertTrue(thrown.getMessage().contentEquals("Name field is required"));
}

private ProductRequest buildProduct() {
    ProductRequest request = new ProductRequest();
//        request.setName("");
    request.setAmount(0);
    request.setPrice(500.0);
    return request;
}

}
```

I get the message from console:

> org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: Expected org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException to be thrown, but nothing was thrown.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvNlf.png)

I've also tried to remove the exception handling from RestExceptionHandler, and launch the app, but in this case I get the massage:

> Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException: Validation failed for argument [0] in public com.guavapay.delivery.dto.response.ProductResponse com.guavapay.delivery.controller.ProductController.createProduct(com.guavapay.delivery.dto.request.ProductRequest): [Field error in object 'productRequest' on field 'name': rejected value []; codes [NotBlank.productRequest.name,NotBlank.name,NotBlank.java.lang.String,NotBlank]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [productRequest.name,name]; arguments []; default message [name]]; default message [Name field is required]] ]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDghU.png)
where the MethodArgumentNotValidException is contained.

And I am confused, what do I need to do that to test the @NotBlank annotation properly and get the MethodArgumentNotValidException for asserting in test?..

Could you advise me anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

firstly, you can quickly unit-test and check how your object is validated like this:

```
@Test
void test2() {
    //given
    Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();
    ProductRequest productMissingName = buildValidProduct();
    productMissingName.setName("");

    //when
    var violations  = validator.validate(productMissingName);
    System.out.println(violations);

    //then
    // ...
}
```

Then, you need to make sure that this validation will happen. So you'll need to add a `@Valid` - you can put it in the controller, or even here in the service class. For instance:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public ProductResponse createProduct(@Valid ProductRequest productRequest) {
    // ...
}
```

Once you have these, it should work with the `@SpringBootTest`, as suggested by @egeorge in the previous answer

Comment: Thank you, it works. I tried similar approach and achieved success.

Comment: I tried the same approach. But I get the below error. `javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000045: A group has to be an interface.` But do not have any groups defined in my entity class.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are bypassing the `Spring` injection, so I would not expect things like the `RestExceptionHandler` to get invoked. I suggest making this a `SpringBootTest`

```
@SpringBootTest
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class ProductServiceTest {
   @Mock ProductRepository productRepository;
   @Autowired ProductMapper productMapper;
   @Autowired ProductServiceImpl productService;

   @Test
   void whenEmptyNameProduct() {
      //...same as before
   }
 }
```

I don't know what mocking framework you use, but this is what the `SpringBoot` `Mockito` version would look like.

Comment: I tried your code, but unfortunately, I,ve got the same result "Expected org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException to be thrown, but nothing was thrown."

Comment: You might need to call the full MVC stack with `MockMVC` for the ExceptionHandler to be included in it.